# I would appreciate your advice on the climate of my world

Tags: climate, weather, map-making

There are some things I don't understand. So far I have my map pretty developed but I think I made some mistakes and there are places I am not sure about. I know I made some mistakes with ocean currents. Also I am not sure how to tackle the sea similar to the Mediterranean. It opens to ocean at its own northeast, 30° north, but I flipped the rotation of the planet because I wanted there to be a Mediterranean climate.

Does the climate around such a sea depend on thr ocean current that flows to it, or would it have a Mediterranean climate anyway? When I search for an ocean currents map, it does not display the Mediterranean.

I also am not sure about high elevated regions. I have many mountains at different latitudes and I wonder how the sides of the mountains would behave. I am not concerned about the tops of the mountains, but the sides of the hills. I once saw a video in which they said that mountains could form a sort of oasis in an otherwise bare climate zone, thanks to lower temperature and higher precipitation.

I do have one mountain range that lays between 0° and 20° north, which divides that Mediterranean sea from the ocean on its southwest, and basically has a similar shape to Central America. Normally I would consider it to be desert or semi-desert but with those features, I am not sure if there should not be a more diverse region with savannah and Mediterranean micro-climates. Also, I am not sure if I should not make those mountains lower, since although they are mountains, they are mainly underwater and they may not reach as high altitude.

[image]

Comment: While the ocean current into Mediterranean is a real and important thing, I'm not sure it is affecting climate there in any significant way (other than keeping Mediterranean sea full).

Comment: I don't think that your Mediterranean should even have mediteranian climate. As I understand it, you get humid  subtropical climate where the winds come from the sea and mediterranean climate when they come from over land. To get what you want, the world would have to rotate retrograde.

Answer (score 2):

well, the world you have a relatively unchanging climate. My guess is the planet has little to no axial tilt, and what caused the mountain ranges on this world was the tidal forces from both the Sun and the moon. So the moon of this world sounds like it's at least half the size of the one here, which means the climate would be milder still.

so weather would be tamer here, and rather uneventful on this world.

also, with mono climate planets, the environment tends to be very uniform throughout the planet with brief to no seasons. given such planets have little to no axial tilt whatsoever.

the means there's areas that'll have an eternal ice-sheet at the poles, and arctic and antarctic regions of the planet.

all in all this planet would be a thing of beauty.

do hope this was satisfactory an answer